# Are these SQL input parameters vulnerable to injection?

Tags: python, regex, django, postgresql

I am working in Django 1.8 with a Postgres 9.4 backend. I am currently running the following query using `django.db.connection`:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
codes = ['01', '02'] # these are actually obtained as GET parameters

query = "SELECT number_str, bnf_id, name FROM mytable WHERE "
for i, code in enumerate(codes):
    q = "(number_str ILIKE '{}%' OR name ~* '{}') "
    query += q.format(code, code)
    if i < len(codes)-1:
        query += 'OR '
cursor.execute(query)
```

This works, but is it vulnerable to SQL injection?

If so, is there some way that I can escape `codes` before passing them into the query string, that will still work with this regex query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that this *is* vulnerable to SQL injection, since you GET your content, `codes` from the user and don't inspect or clean it before putting it in your query.

A better way of ensuring your SQL command is escaped could be to use `execute` as follows:

```
query = "SELECT number_str, bnf_id, name FROM mytable WHERE "
for i, code in enumerate(codes):
    q = "(number_str ILIKE %s OR name ~* %s) "
    query += q
    if i < len(codes)-1:
        query += 'OR '

# create an interleaved list of '<code>%', '<code>' pairs:
qcodes1 = [s + '%' for s in codes]
qcodes2 = codes
qcodes = [code for p in zip(qcodes1, qcodes2) for code in p]

cursor.execute(query, qcodes)
```

(NB the comma instead of `%` in `execute`).

By the way, what is wrong with Django's querysets for this type of query?

Comment: Thanks. It's a `startswith` query not an `is equal to` query, so I can't check that the codes are valid ones. I can't guarantee they're integers, either, they could be alphabetical strings. (This is for an autocomplete field where the user may query by code or name.) But I guess I could look for colons and brackets and so on?

Comment: I can't use a Django queryset because I need to query a materialized view, which has the list of unique names.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `escape_string()` from `MySQLDb` library to quote the strings:

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id5